# Is it possible to create an extension to vscode that changes the CSS of the editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I wish to develop an open-source WYSIWYG editor for markdown in vscode.

See the image below. I want an extension that can do something like that.

1. Change font-sizes for lines for titles.
2. Change lines indentation for subtitles.

I'm looking at the extension reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api and don't see something that can help.

Do you have an idea how to change the CSS of the editor based on rules? in addition, If you have a link to extension that did it may help.

**In other words**: How a vscode extension can change css style of the editor window?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't change arbitrary css in the editor. See the extension guide for [info about the VS Code extension philosophy](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/overview#restrictions) and [how you can extend VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/overview)

Two options:

- Use the [decorations api](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/decorator-sample) to change rendering of tokens in the editor.
- Use a [webview](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview) to implement a custom view (but don't try re-implementing a text-editor because it will be a pain and will not work like VS Code's normal editors do)